# I get error 7 while updating Cyanogen OS 13 on OnePlus

Tags: updates, ota-update, twrp, oneplus-one, cyanogen-os

I have OnePlus One with Cyanogen OS 13.0-ZNH0EAS2JK and I can't install OTA updates since I have TWRP as recovery (version 3.0.2-0).

So, for this reason I downloaded the file of incremental version (this one: http://builds.cyngn.com/incremental/bacon/cm-bacon-ced5430fc0-to-9f339bddf2-signed.zip) and I tried to install it from recovery, but I get the following error:

`Click to enlarge`

[image]

Here is the message i get every time i reboot the phone:

[image]

How can i solve?

Comment: The reason of the failure is explained in the log itself: the ZIP is made to update a different COS version (either **MHC19Q/ZNH2KAS1KN**, or **MHC19Q/ZNH2KAS254**) than yours (**LMY48B/YOG4PAS1NO**), therefore the check (or **assert**) fails, preventing you from updating. The check is in place because updating from a version different than the accepted ones may break the system, and this check mechanism is pretty common in all of Cyanogen's ZIPs.

Comment: I see, thank you for your explanation. So how to update my phone? (i edited my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I followed recommendation of other forum [Cm13.1 ZCN2KAS1KN](https://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/126028-update-help-to-znh2kas1kn/) i.e get  updated cyanogen os 13.1 official full zip and dirty patched to this official succesfully. Having TWRP implies we lost incremental updates...